# Kotlin unhandled coroutine exception does not crash

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I expected the following program to crash but it doesn't. It just prints that an exception occurred in a thread and exits normally. Why?

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.*

fun main() {
    val scope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default)
    
    scope.launch {
        delay(100)
        throw RuntimeException("1")
    }
    
    println("sleep")
    Thread.sleep(1000)
    println("exit without crash")
}
```

[playground](https://pl.kotl.in/A6iosN9YL)

Comment: I’m not sure how to answer since you didn’t say why you would expect it to crash. It doesn’t crash because that’s the defined behavior. The thread running `main` doesn’t encounter any exceptions in your code.

Comment: I guess I should have asked: How to propagate the exception to the main thread so that it'd crash?

Comment: `val job = scope.launch { ... }; runBlocking { job.join() }`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you're creating your own `CoroutineScope`, you have your own top-level coroutine which is not bound to the main thread. Creating a `CoroutineScope` manually [also implies manual cleanup](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-coroutine-scope/) (otherwise you have the same pitfalls as `GlobalScope` and may leak coroutines or lose errors).

The main program only crashes if the main thread crashes, and the main thread doesn't crash here. If you want to have a relationship between this main thread and the launched coroutines (and propagate exceptions), you should use structured concurrency from the beginning.

For instance, using `runBlocking` at the top of your `main()` function creates a `CoroutineScope` (available as `this`) which serves as parent for all launched coroutines. It also blocks the main thread while waiting for all the child coroutines, and propagates exceptions. You don't need your own scope then:

```kotlin
fun main() {
    runBlocking(Dispatchers.Default) { // using Dispatchers.Default to be equivalent with your code
    
        launch { // using "this" CoroutineScope from runBlocking
            delay(100)
            throw RuntimeException("1")
        }
    
        println("sleep")
        delay(1000) // using delay instead of Thread.sleep because we're in a coroutine now
        println("exit without crash")
    }
}
```

This way you get:

```
sleep
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: 1
 at FileKt$main$1$1.invokeSuspend (File.kt:16) 
 at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith (ContinuationImpl.kt:33) 
 at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run (DispatchedTask.kt:106)
```